# What happens to gold and nitra after a dive?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic-survivor

After a dive ends, what happens to the gold and nitra accumulated through the five levels of the dive? Is it converted into gold for permanent upgrades, or is that awarded as an unrelated currency?